# Restart Regex indexing based on line content

Tags: c#, regex, indexing

I am trying to load a text file into a C# ContentBox and index the lines.

Currently the text file contains

```
Data
Company
Phone
Email
Company
Phone
Email
```

I have currently setup a Refex index to number all the lines in the text file on load.

```cs
string content = File.ReadAllText(file);

content = Regex.Replace(content, @"^\s*$\n|\r", string.Empty, RegexOptions.Multiline).TrimEnd();
var index = 0;
content = Regex.Replace(content, "^", (Match m) => (index++).ToString().PadLeft(4, '0') + " ", RegexOptions.Multiline);
ContentBox.Text = content;
```

This outputs

```
0000 Data
0001 Company
0002 Phone
0003 Email
0004 Company
0005 Phone
0006 Email
```

What I need to do is be able to output the following into the ContentBox.

```
0000 Data
0001 Company
0002 Phone
0003 Email
0001 Company
0002 Phone
0003 Email
```

Can anyone assist me with this?

Comment: Is that literally what your text file contains or are you saying those of place holders for the actual data?

Comment: Also your code presented does not output what you say that it outputs. It is only outputting the list of numbers. What output do you actually want?

Comment: Just noticed the code is indented on line where `var index = 0;` which suggests it's kind of part of a function call from the previous line, but that's not the case.

Comment: Hi @Enigmativity, they are placeholders of the data that is actually in the text file. The code does output what I've stated above in Visual Studio.

Comment: @sln sorry my fault, I had coppied the indenting from Visual studio.

Answer (score 0):

Your use of Regex is not needed. This code should give you the direction you need:

```
string[] content =
    File
        .ReadAllText(file)
        .Select((x, n) => $"{(n == 0 ? 0 : (n - 1) % 3 + 1):0000} {x}")
        .ToArray();
```

Here's an example of it working:

```
    string[] source = @"Data
ABC Bakery
0123
abc@bakery.com
DEF Pets
0124
def@pets.com".Split(Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    string[] content =
        source
            .Select((x, n) => $"{(n == 0 ? 0 : (n - 1) % 3 + 1):0000} {x}")
            .ToArray();
```

That gives:

```
0000 Data 
0001 ABC Bakery 
0002 0123 
0003 abc@bakery.com 
0001 DEF Pets 
0002 0124 
0003 def@pets.com
```

Comment: If you want to give the same index for same line content, consider this: `var content = source.Select(x => $"{source.IndexOf(x):0000} {x}").ToArray();`

Comment: @SGKoishi - Why do that when `.Select((x, n)` works and is `o(n)`? Doing an `.IndexOf` is `o(n^2)` in this case.

Comment: @SGKoishi - And worse, the `.IndexOf` will return the wrong value when there are duplicates in the source.

Comment: `.Select((x, n)` returns current index, but `.IndexOf` returns first occurrence.

Comment: @SGKoishi - Oh, sorry, I see your point now. But why would you want the first occurrence?

Comment: From OP's expected output, `Company` is 0001 (twice). I'm not sure where the numbers from, a `0001-0002-0003` loop or first occurrence.

Comment: @SGKoishi - The OP explained in the comments that the text file contains actual company names, phone numbers, and emails. He's just used `Company`, `Phone`, and `Email` as placeholders for the real values.